# Alice Faker library choose random from array

Tags: symfony, nelmio-alice, alice-fixtures

I am trying to generate a dummy data using [AliceBundle](https://github.com/hautelook/AliceBundle) for Symfony Framework. Everything seems to be working fine except I am looking for a way to randomly assign data from an array to a property called `type`. Looking at the [faker library](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker#fakerproviderbase) I can see that I can generate that using `randomElement($array = array ('a','b','c'))`

I am trying to convert that into `YML` and I think that is equivalent of

```
<randomElement(['a','b','c'])>
```

But this produces an error

> [Nelmio\Alice\Throwable\Exception\FixtureBuilder\ExpressionLanguage\LexException]
>   Could not lex the value "['a'".

This is my complete `yml`

```
AppBundle\Entity\Job:
    job{1..5}:
        title: <jobTitle()>
        description: <paragraph(3)>
        length: "3_months_full_time"
        type: <randomElement(['a','b','c'])>
        bonus: <paragraph(3)>
        expired_at: "2016-12-21"
        job_user: "@emp*"
```

Comment: Have you tried `<randomElement($array = array ('a', 'b', 'c'))>`?

Comment: Yes i did, thats throws an error Could not find a variable "array".

Comment: You might need to quote the entire result, like `type: "<randomElement(['a', 'b', 'c'])>"`.

Comment: @Oldskool nope that does not work, that too throws LexException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a custom provider

```
namespace AppBundle\DataFixtures\Faker\Provider;

    class JobTypeProvider
    {
        public static function jobType()
        {
            $types = array("paid", "unpaid", "contract");
            $typeIndex = array_rand($types);
            return  $types[$typeIndex];
        }
    }
```

Add that to `services.yml`

```
app.data_fixtures_faker_provider.job_type_provider:
    class: AppBundle\DataFixtures\Faker\Provider\JobTypeProvider
    tags: [ { name: nelmio_alice.faker.provider } ]
```

And then use it in yml file

```
AppBundle\Entity\Job:
    job{1..50}:
        title: <jobTitle()>
        description: <paragraph(3)>
        length: <jobLength()>
        job_industry: "@title*"
        type: <jobType()>
        bonus: <paragraph(3)>
        expired_at: "2016-12-21"
        job_user: "@emp*"
```

> Notice type: , this is being generated from service now.

Answer (score 6):

This works for me:

```
parameters:
    profileArray: ['PUBLIC', 'PRIVATE', 'AUTHENTICATED']

JobPlatform\AppBundle\Entity\Profile:
    profiles_{1..100}:
        user: '@user_<current()>'
        visibility: <randomElement($profileArray)>
```